# Why does dnorm() not return the standard deviation I inputted when I do sd(dnorm())?

Tags: r, gaussian, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

This may be a dumb question, however I don't understand why `sd(dnorm(1:100, mean=50, sd=15))` doesn't return the standard deviation as `[1] 15.0` instead of what it actually returns which is `[1] 0.009440673`. When I do this with rnorm() `sd(rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=15))` it returns what I would expect which is a number close to 15:  `[1] 17.00682`. Can someone please explain why `sd(dnorm(x,mean=mean,sd=sd))` doesn't return the standard deviation that I input to dnorm?

Comment: Please check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157662/rnorm-vs-dnorm-in-r)

Comment: There also exist `pnorm` and `qnorm`. You can spend some time understanding the difference between the four `norm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) function returns the density of the normal distribution with the mean (50) and standard deviation (15) you gave it.

On the other hand, rnorm will sample 100 numbers over a normal distribution, that's why you get standard deviations close to 15.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression dnorm was returning samples for a normal distribution not the density. Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 3):

It's always helpful to plot your data. If you try `hist(dnorm(1:100, mean=50, sd=15))` you'll see that the variability is very small (see below). As MkWTF points out, that's because `dnorm` returns the value of the probability density function of the normal distribution at value x given specified `mean` and `sd`.

`rnorm` in contrast generates random numbers with probability given by the probability density function of the normal distribution, which is why it allows a sensible estimate of the SD - the generated values follow that distribution.

The documentation for dnorm/pnorm/qnorm/rnorm is not great in my opinion (as someone who lacks a background in mathematics), but if you spend some time reading different online resources about these functions, and ensuring that you understand the meaning of the different underlying concepts (probability density functions, quantiles, random number generation, and (cumulative) distribution functions, it will become clear over time.

```r
hist(dnorm(1:100, mean=50, sd=15))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks that makes sense I was just confused with what dnorm was returning to me.